# Python subclass loses subclass attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, attr, shapely

This is question based on the [shapely package](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) but I think it's a more general question.

Basically I have two classes coming from shapely. One is called `Point` and the other is called `MultiPoint`. You instantiate `Point` with a tuple of coordinates and `MultiPoint` with a list of `Point`. You can access the points in multipoint using indexing.

```
 p1 = Point((1,1))
 p2 = Point((2,2))
 mp = MultiPoint([p1,p2])

 In [315]: MultiPoint((p1, p2))[0]
 Out[315]: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1049b1f50>
```

I want to subclass `Point` and use it for the location of a car.

```
class Car(Point):
    def __init__(self, coords, speed):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(coords)
        self.speed = speed
```

Now I can write

```
 c1 = Car((1,1), speed=2)
 c2 = Car((2,2), speed=3)
 mc = MultiPoint([c1,c2])
```

I can access the cars using indexing but they are no longer cars. They are points. In particular they have no attribute speed.

```
In [316]: MultiPoint((c1, c2))[0]
Out[316]: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1049b1610>

In [317]: MultiPoint((c1, c2))[0].speed
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'speed'
```

Is there a way of fixing this by subclassing Multipoint? I guess I don't know what happens to cars (points) when they are passed to MultiPoint.

Edit: I made a mistake typing the code example for `c1` and `c2`. It's fixed now. I wasn't instantiating points, I was instantiating cars.

Comment: Is your "now I can write" example supposed to be calling `Car` rather than `Point`? If so, I suspect the answer to this comes down completely on how `MultiPoint` is implemented. If it just contains the objects passed into it, you should be able to make it work. However, if it's unpacking the coordinates from the `Point` instances it's passed and putting them into some other kind of data structure (perhaps a C array), then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @Blckknght. Thanks for pointing out my error. It's fixed. I sort of suspected I might be out of luck. I guess I was looking for guiding organizational principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `MultiPoint` class is conceptually a collection of `Point`s, it's not actually keeping a reference to the `Point` instance (or instances of a `Point` subclass) that you pass in to its constructor. Rather, it copies the coordinates from the point into its own internal data structure. This loses the extra attributes you've added to your `Car` subclass. Here's the brief passage in [the docs](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#MultiPoint):

> The constructor also accepts another `MultiPoint` instance or an unordered sequence of `Point` instances, thereby making copies.

I'd suggest designing your `Car` class to have an attribute that is a `Point` (or maybe a reference to a `MultiPoint` and an index), rather than making it be a subclass of `Point`. Inheriting from another conceptually unrelated type is usually a bad idea when you can use encapsulation instead.

It can help clarify your design to remember that inheritance means "IS-A", while encapsulation means "HAS-A". For instance, a rectangle IS-A shape, so if you write a `Shape` class, a `Rectangle` would be a perfectly reasonable subclass. In your case, your inheritance suggests that a `Car` IS-A `Point`, which doesn't make much sense. It would make more sense to say that a `Car` HAS-A `position` (which is a `Point`).

Comment: Ok. That's a good paradigm to remember and very helpful. If I add a Point attribute to car, can I then go backwards and use a point to access the car instance that it is an attribute of. I ask because I want to ask questions about locations of cars - eg. what cars are nearby?

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate the `Car` objects with the `Car` class constructor:

```
 c1 = Car((1,1), speed=2)
 c2 = Car((2,2), speed=3)
 mc = MultiPoint([c1,c2])
```

Python follows the duck typing principle:

> If it quacks like a duck and looks like a duck, then it must be a
>   duck.

This makes Polymorphism very easy. Your objects **are** not any particular class, they **behave** according to their superclasses. This behaviour can be different in different circumstances.

Your `MultiPoint` class will glady accept `Car` objects in place of `Point` objects.

I'm curious about your `Point` class, could you post it?

Comment: I made a mistake typing up the example code. I meant it to read exactly as you've written it. It still doesn't play nice with `MultiPoint`. My question is fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: The point class comes from the [shapely package](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html#module-shapely.geometry.point).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 c1 = Point((1,1), speed=2)
 c2 = Point((2,2), speed=3)
 mc = MultiPoint([c1,c2])
```

According to the description you had to instantiate Car objects, not Points:

```
c1 = Car((1,1), 2)
c2 = Car((2,2), 3)
```

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake in typing. I fixed the example.